# R - New column in data frame with aggregated value based on three conditions

Tags: r

Suppose I have the data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(Year = rep(1:3, each = 5)
                 , Terminal = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2)
                 , day = c (1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2)
                 , Capacity = sample(1:15))
```

and trying to get a columnb "X" that is a sum of capacity for the same year, day and terminal.

Original df

[image]

Outcome:

[image]

I use below codes to do the calculations:

```
aggregate(Capacity ~ Terminal + Year + day , data=df, FUN=sum)
```

and

```
as.data.table(df)[, sum(Capacity), by = .(Terminal, Year, day)]
```

but when I try to create the new column it only prints either 1 or 2 value and not the sum. Also it gives the below warring. The code I have for the X is `df["X"] <- aggregate(Capacity ~ Terminal + Year + day , data=df, FUN=sum)`

Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "X", value = list(Terminal = c(1, 1,  :
  provided 4 variables to replace 1 variables

Answer (score 2):

The `aggregate` returns a summarised output and not create a new column.  We can use `mutate` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(Year, day, Terminal) %>%
   mutate(X = sum(Capacity))
```

For the `data.table` approach we need to assign `:=` to create a new column

```
as.data.table(df)[, X := sum(Capacity), by = .(Terminal, Year, day)]
```

---

Or with `ave` from `base R`

```
df$X <- with(df, ave(Capacity, Year, day, Terminal, FUN = sum))
```

Comment: Thanks akrun, the last code works, for some reason the mutate won't create the column. It prints df and it does calculate thou. Any idea why, I tried simple example and it worked: `df <- data.frame("A" = 1:6,
                 "B" = 7:12)
df <- mutate(df, C = A + B)`

Comment: @Kalenji  You need to assign the output back to original dataset i.e. `df <- df %>% group_by(..`

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Full code for anyone to re-use it. `df <- df %>%
  group_by(Year, day, Terminal) %>%
  mutate(X = sum(Capacity))`